# Blackberry Push Notification Clicking on the indicator area of the Home Screen brings up a notification summary

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

After doing hard work i am getting push notification.

**WHAT I WANT**

BlackBerry® Clicking on the indicator area of the Home Screen brings up a notification summary.

**WHAT CURRENTLY SHOWING**

you currently have no new notification

**And here is my code**

```java
 private static void updateIndicator( int inc ) {
    ApplicationFolderIntegrationConfig config = new   ApplicationFolderIntegrationConfig(
            false, false, ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor());

    //Register the ApplicationMessageFolder
    //ReadableListImpl source is available in the messagelistdemo.
    ApplicationMessageFolder folder = ApplicationMessageFolderRegistry.getInstance().registerFolder(
            0x33c7ce29883abe5fL, "Test Folder", new ReadableListImpl(), config);

    //DemoMessage source is available in the messagelistdemo.
    DemoMessage msg = new DemoMessage("me@here.com", "Pizza Toppings", 
            "What would you like on your pizza?", System.currentTimeMillis());
    folder.fireElementAdded((ApplicationMessage) msg);

    //Display the application indicator icon.

    //#ifndef HANDHELD_VERSION_42
    // update indicator if device software is 4.6 or greater
    ApplicationIndicatorRegistry indicatorRegistry = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();
    ApplicationIndicator indicator = indicatorRegistry.getApplicationIndicator();
    boolean refresh;
    if( indicator == null ) {
        ApplicationIcon icon = new ApplicationIcon( EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource( "app_icon_small.png" ) );
        indicator = indicatorRegistry.register( icon, false, true );
        refresh = true;
    } else {
        refresh = inc == 0;
    }

    int unreadCount = 0;
    if( refresh ) {
        PushMessage[] messages = PersistentStorage.getMessages();
        for( int i = messages.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            if( messages[ i ].isUnread() ) {
                unreadCount++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        unreadCount = indicator.getValue() + inc;
    }

    indicator.setValue( unreadCount );
    if( unreadCount > 0 ) {
        indicator.setVisible( true );
    } else {
        indicator.setVisible( false );
    }
    //#endif
}
```

I am using blackberry push notification sample

I don't know what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions thrown?  Some of those methods can throw exceptions.  Also, have you stepped through this code in the debugger?  You should.  Check if you get all the way to `indicator.setVisible(true)`.

Comment: hi got it working but now i have new problem On click on push notification from home screen it should redirect my App can u please give me some suggestion on this.

Comment: If you have solved this problem, please post your solution below as an **answer**.  Or, you can delete this question.  Thanks.

Comment: this is the code i was missing  folder.fireElementAdded(msg, false);